# istio unable to access kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, networking, https, istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to access the [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) through an [Istio Gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/) + [Virtual Service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/).

However, all I get is `404 page not found` when I try to access the dashboard with browser. Accessing the Dashboard through k8s NodePort or k8s LoadBalancer service works just as expected. The pod, however, complains in the logs about `http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.6:52483: remote error: tls: bad certificate`.

Running `httpbin` through Istio (as given in their documentation) works as expected, so Istio seem to be working fine as well.

I am using the official Kubernetes Dashboard YAML-s. I am giving the service below (with `type: LoadBalancer` added, although it doesn't seem to make a difference for Istio, although it allows me to access the Dashboard through a separate IP).

Just for the record, my k8s cluster is comprised of VirtualBox machines running [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

`kubectl get services --all-namespaces` returns the following:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                      AGE
default                kubernetes                        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>          443/TCP                                      11d
httpbin                httpbin                           ClusterIP      10.100.186.188   <none>          8000/TCP                                     47h
istio-system           istio-egressgateway               ClusterIP      10.109.231.163   <none>          80/TCP,443/TCP                               5d3h
istio-system           istio-ingressgateway              LoadBalancer   10.111.188.94    192.168.56.46   15021:31440/TCP,80:31647/TCP,443:32715/TCP   5d3h
istio-system           istiod                            ClusterIP      10.104.236.247   <none>          15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP        5d3h
kube-system            kube-dns                          ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                       11d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper         ClusterIP      10.101.131.136   <none>          8000/TCP                                     43h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-service      LoadBalancer   10.103.130.244   192.168.56.47   443:30041/TCP                                43h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-service-np   NodePort       10.100.49.224    <none>          8443:30002/TCP                               43h
```

If I try to access the LoadBalancer directly via the IP from above and through browser, I get the usual Kubernetes Dashboard login page. The browser url is `https://192.168.56.47`.

YAML-s:

istio-gateway.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-gateway
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: PASSTHROUGH
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

istio-virtual-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-virtual-service
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - kubernetes-dashboard-gateway
  tls:
    - match:
        - sniHosts: ["*"]
      route:
        - destination:
            host: kubernetes-dashboard-service
            port:
              number: 443
```

dashboard-service.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-service
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
    # - port: 8000
    #   targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: How exactly do you try to connect your dashboard? Please attach your full curl command with the URL.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak, thank you - I have added more information. Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: your gateway is listening 443. not 80.

Comment: @suren, @MikołajGłodziak, I've updated the question with more details. I got the HTTPS working via TLS passthrough and specifying `sniHosts` in the Virtual Service. Now I get `404 page not found` again when I try to access it in browser. Just FYI, I also get a warning about visiting a page with self-signed certificate, which I ignore.

Answer (score 0):

User [suren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5564578/suren) has mentioned:

> your gateway is listening 443. not 80

Yes, this could be a problem. You are trying to reach port 80, but you are exposing only port 443. Try to change your configuration or change your port during request.

See albo documentation about [Deploy and Access the Kubernetes Dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I got it working with the configuration as above and with explicitly specifying a host in all places where I have previously placed a `"*"`. I had to add that host in `/etc/hosts` to be able to access it in browser.

It seems that this last part was key, as well as specifying the `sniHost` in the Virtual Service. The other problems were mostly configuration issues with the TLS. Setting it to `PASSTHROUGH` seems to work, because it forces Istio to sort of forward the HTTPS request to the Kubernetes Dashboard, which is responsible for decrypting etc.